# How can we use multiple fields from an external list in a survey?

Tags: survey-list, external-list, lookup-column

We are trying to build a survey, that uses data from an external list.

It works fine for a single field.

But what we would like to do is to bring about 10 fields back from the external system and place then in the survey list.

Anyone know if this is possible, or do we need to build a form over a standard custom list?

Comment: Do you want to display the values when the user is filling out the survey or when the results of the survey are being displayed?

Comment: Actually both, after posting the question, I have found that I can get at all the values when the survey is over using reporting services, but the user also needs to see the values while the survey is being filled out

Comment: @Marek, we just used the Designer to create the survey, no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for this type of scenario is to use InfoPath.  With InfoPath, you can lookup information from SharePoint lists and have associated information display on the form when it does so.

The standard SharePoint lists can only display the associated fields once the survey response has been created (submitted).